# Comparing current NSUserDefaults values with previous NSUserDefaults?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I'm using following code to store values in `NSUserDefaults`.

```
 NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
 [defaults setObject:jsonDic[@"value"][@"shipment_version"] forKey:@"shipment_version"];
 [defaults synchronize];
```

Im using the following code to retrieve those values.

```
NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString* strValue =    [defaults objectForKey:@"shipment_version"];
NSLog(@"%@",strValue);
```

When the user presses sync now button, it should check for updates by comparing already existing `shipment_version` value with current shipment_version value. Is there any ways through which I can do this?

Comment: "it should check for updates".  So what are you finding difficult doing that?

Answer (score 0):

literally looking for 'shipping' version, then we already know the version before shipping either hardcoded or changed by script from SCM (like git or p4 or clear case) in all these case it is better be in plist file

Actions can be done by conditional checks in major (minor not recommended) version check.

If you are checking for version change in server then it is good to be in nsuerdefaults. Here server request should return version which can be used to decide to do some update (after update, change user default value)